# How to embed continuous values in conditional difussion models?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

When we want to use embeddings for discrete labels as conditional information in diffusion models, we first convert the labels to time embedding dimensions using `nn.Embedding(num_classes, time_dim)` and then adding it to the positional encoding output and passing it through the model.

How can this embedding be done if we have continuous values instead of discrete labels? If we divide the values into bins and make them categorical data, we will lose important information. Is it possible to do it with minimum loss?